# Change element position inside MovieClip in Event.RESIZE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

OK I have some little listener.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,rozmiar1);
            function rozmiar1(e:Event):void
            {
            ofertaBTN.oCenter.width=(14.59*stage.stageWidth)/100;
            ofertaBTN.oRight.x = ofertaBTN.x+ofertaBTN.oLeft.width +ofertaBTN.Ocenter.width;
            }
```

But only ofertaBTN.oCenter.width is changing. oRight is not responding and I get error #1010. Could you give me any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have written variable name badly: `Ocenter` instead of `oCenter` in your second statement